# async/await approach for Fire and Forgot

Tags: c#, winforms, asynchronous, async-await

Let's say I have the following code in a winforms app.

```
    private async Task<decimal> DivAsync(int a, int b)
    {
        await TaskEx.Delay(2000);
        return a / b;
    }

    private async Task DivAsyncWithErrorHandling(int a, int b)
    {
        try
        {
            await DivAsync(a, b);
        }
        catch (DivideByZeroException)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("DivAsync({0}, {1}) failed", a, b);
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DivAsyncWithErrorHandling(5, 0);
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TaskEx.Run(() => DivAsyncWithErrorHandling(5, 0));
    }

    private async void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await DivAsyncWithErrorHandling(5, 0);
        await SomeThingElse();
    }
```

Obviously my real word code does something else. The point is, I already have error handling. The code  `DivAsyncWithErrorHandling` may be run with `await` (see example `button3_Click`) so I can not use as `async void` approach but also may be run with fire and forgot.

`button1_Click` and `button2_Click` both produce the excepted result (`DivAsyncWithErrorHandling` is run asynchronous without blocking the ui but with differt advantages / disadvantages.

`button1_Click` shows a warning `Because this call is not awaited, execution ... continues before the call is complete.` but has less code

[image]

`button2_Click` does not show a warning, but has more code to write and uses another Task.

So my question is. What would be the best solution in this case? Ignore the warning and use `button1` or use `button2`.

Maybe there is a better solution already buildin similar to `task.RunSynchronously` but with fire and forgot.

`DivAsyncWithErrorHandling(5, 0).RunAsynchronously();`

The purpose is to convert an "Old style" routine which takes an optional action to continue after completion to async/await pattern

```
    private DivAsyncWithErrorHandlingOld(int a, int b, Action after = null)
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            try
            {
                Div(a, b);
            }
            catch (DivideByZeroException)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("DivAsync({0}, {1}) failed", a, b);
            }
            after?.Invoke();
        });
    }
```

Comment: How about making `DivAsyncWithErrorHandling` return `void`? I understand that this say "you can never await this method" but if this method, in this case, isn't supposed to be awaited but *is supposed to be fire and forget everywhere it is called*, then this is the right solution.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen It may be awaited (see `button3_Click`) but not everywhere in my code base.

Comment: Are you targeting an unsupported .NET version? All *supported* versions have `Task.Run`, not `TaskEx.Run`

Comment: As for differences - `DivAsync` doesn *not* run asynchronously, until the first `await` is encountered. `button2_Click` is fully fire-and-forget while `button1_Click` isn't.

Comment: What the method does matters in this context. Is it IO or CPU bound? For IO work, eg calling multiple web services, you can just call the method. If it contains a lot of CPU work befor the first IO, you need Task.Run

Comment: Finally, upgrade to a supported .NET version (4.5.2+) and check ActionBlock<T>. It allows you to post messages to a queue for asynchronous processing by 1 or more tasks with a bounded queue length to allow throttling. You can use it to ensure there aren't any fire-and-forget jobs still running when closing the application

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos It's Framework 4.0 with `Microsoft.BCL.Async` but it would be the same for 4.5.

Comment: @JürgenSteinblock There is no TaskEx in 4.5+. In any case, if the method is well written and asynchronous , there's no reason to use `Task.Run`. Task.Run is ONLY meant for CPU-bound work. Methods that do both heavy CPU and IO work should be rare. That's why it *does* matter what the actual method does

Comment: BTW You could replace the click event handler with the contents of `DivAsyncWithErrorHandling` and still have a "fire-and-forget" call. The UI won't block, the button won't be disabled, assuming `DivAsync` is well-behaved. There's no reason to wrap `DivAsync` in another method the way you did

Comment: Finally, check Stephen Cleary's [Task.Run etiquette and proper usage](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/10/taskrun-etiquette-and-proper-usage.html). It explains *why* Task.Run is only to call CPU-bound methods, why you *shouldn't* put Task.Run inside such a method but have the caller use Task.Run etc

Answer (score -1):

Go with Task.Run since it's more obvious what is going on and it's the recommended approach.

"The Run methods are the preferred way to create and start tasks when more control over the creation and scheduling of the task is not needed."
Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-based-asynchronous-programming

"If the work you have is CPU-bound and you care about responsiveness, use async and await but spawn the work off on another thread with Task.Run."
Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/async

Comment: It's not the "recommended approach". That's not what the documentation says. The snippet you copied is from a paragraph that compares cold and hot tasks. The question is whether to use `await` or not. There *are* differences that have nothing to do with control

Comment: Fair enough, but it's still recommended because Task.Run starts the work in another thread thus freeing up the calling (UI) thread which is, I presume, the point.

Comment: Compared to what? The question isn't how to run something in the background. All the options posted by the OP use tasks already. And [Task.Run](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Task.cs,5614) **IS** the same as [Task.Factory.StartNew](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/TaskFactory.cs,300) with different defaults

Comment: Compared to simply calling an async method without "await".
Task.Run *IS* the same and it should be used in this case to preserve functionality *and* follow async/await control flow, as Jürgen wants.

Comment: The last comment is simply wrong. It's *not* the same and shouldn't be used blindly. In fact, if the first method of `DivAsync` is `await`, using `Task.Run` will simply waste one task to start another task.

Comment: In fact, one could say that the recommended approach is to NOT use Task.Run on a method suffixed with `Async` that returns a Task. The method's implementer explicitly tells you the method is already asynchronous, why assume that's a lie? Why wrap the task in another task and have to call `.Result.Result`? If you are the implementer, it's up to you to ensure there are no expensive calls before the asynchronous calls

Comment: I'm not assuming it's a lie, I'm assuming that I'm not sure what it does and if it's a fire-and-forget scenario, ability to run that async method on a different thread seems like a preferred way over using the UI thread to do it. And Task.Run enables it to run on a different thread.

Comment: Would you write `await result = Task.Run(()=>httpClient.GetStringAsync(.))` then? Why not? You aren't *certain* what `GetStringAsync` does. And what would that result look like? It wouldn't be a string. Anyway, what you describe is definitely not preferred or recommended in any way.

Comment: The call to await Task.Delay means that the asynchronous work is *ALREADY* off the UI thread. You don't need to use Task.Run to make it run in the background.

Comment: await Task.Delay is just a placeholder for this example. In reality there's some processing that takes a long while, I assume. And why would Task.Delay ensure that work is done on a different thread? As far as I know, async/await doesn't mean multithreading, only asynchronicity.

EDIT: With noteable distinction of Asp.net, due to thread agility.

Comment: Your assumptions are wrong, including ASP.NET. You don't *need* a different thread for an asynchronous IO operation. It's performed by the OS using IO completion ports and a callback is called when the IO completes. This is no different in ASP.NET.

Comment: You should probably read Stephen Cleary's series of articles on [Task.Run etiquette and proper usage](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/10/taskrun-etiquette-and-proper-usage.html). It covers even the rare case of having to [mix heavy CPU and IO work in the same method](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/taskrun-etiquette-examples-even-in.html). That's the only case, where Task.Run should be used if the implementer **clearly** specifies that there is a lot of CPU work involved. A better option would be to break the method in two separate parts if possible